# Clean user input by intercepting postback - Globally - ASP.Net 3.5 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, master-pages, postback

I have an existing project, so I need a solid way of cleaning/checking user input, globally.

I have a Master page (parent) that has the `form` tag, and the "children" pages contains the form elements with the post back commands, insert/update/delete to database etc.

**Using C# only - Is there some way I can globally intercept the postbacks before post runs through the child page?**

**And is it possible to check if it's a textbox/checkbox/radioButton etc. to manipulate cleaning of user input differently?**

Comment: Have you tried Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);?

Comment: Redirect will loose the posted data :(

Comment: @Marc you could use [Html Sanitizer](http://roberto.open-lab.com/2010/03/04/a-html-sanitizer-for-c/) but you will need to turn off ASP.NET validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did to get it working.

- Override the OnInit event on my MasterPage
- Disable the ReadOnly for my Request collection so it is settable.
- Loop through Posted .Net Controls, Sanitize value and set new value.
- Re-enable ReadOnly.

**Works great globally and saved me days of manual labour :)**

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);

        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            var fCollection = (NameValueCollection)Request.GetType().GetField("_form", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(Request);
            PropertyInfo oReadable = fCollection.GetType().GetProperty("IsReadOnly", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            oReadable.SetValue(fCollection, false, null);

            foreach (string s in Request.Params.Keys)
            {
                var pCtrl = Page.FindControl(s);

                //Sanitize the posted values (TextHandler.SimpleSanitize is my own static method)
                if (pCtrl != null) fCollection[s] = TextHandler.SimpleSanitize(fCollection[s]);
            }

            oReadable.SetValue(fCollection, true, null);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Nevber thought of accessing readonly, internal etc fields using reflection - very usefull

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do something with a custom IHttpModule that handles the context.BeginRequest event.

```
public class MyHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(OnBeginRequest);
    }

    protected void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var context = ((HttpApplication) sender).Context;
        // do something here, use the context to get request info
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

You have to register the HttpModule in web.config, something like:

```
<httpModules>
  <add name="MyHttpModule" type="MyProject.MyNamespace.MyHttpModule, MyProject"/>
</httpModules>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add Jquery function at your MasterPage markup which will intercept all events you need and do somth you need. For catching only need controls you can apply css class

Comment: Make base page for all your content pages and implement a recursive function in there with FindControl and checking type. And name ContentHolder control being intercepted same everywhere to simplify search

Comment: The MasterPage is the base for all content pages. Checking the type of control will be handled once I get a proper answer for my first issue..How to catch all the posted data...!

Comment: If you look at your content page cs file you'll see smth like public partial class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page. MasterPage is just outer div. That is all. Once again. Make recursive function in OnInit when IsPostBack = true